# Errors while using the tcolorbox package in Lyx

Tags: lyx, tcolorbox

I started using the wonderful tcolorbox package in Lyx. As can be seen in the first and second pictures, I added the module "fancy color boxes" in the settings, and then chose "insert" > "custom insets" > "color box".

[image]

[image]

I also added these commands to the preamble:

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{tikz}

I tried modifying the design of the color box, as can be seen in the following picture:

[image]

I added a color box options inset, inside the color box, and wrote a simple command for the title of the box, its background color, and its frame color.

I got the error above. I searched it on the internet, but couldn't find a way to fix it.
Does anybody know what is the problem, and how can it be fixed?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently Lyx "adds" the command \textenglish to the color box options, because it "thinks" I changed the language to English (I write my document in Hebrew).

The solution is adding the following commands to the local layout of the document:

```
Format 66
InsetLayout Flex:Color_Box

  Argument 1

    LabelString         "Color Box Options"

    Tooltip             "Insert the color box options here (see tcolorbox manual)"

    PassThru       1

  EndArgument

    ResetsFont true
End
```

*Many* thanks to Udi Foglle (who is an honored member of this community) who told me what was the problem, and instructed me how to fix it. I wouldn't be able to answer my own question without his help. So, all the credit goes to Udi.